# copying single character using std::copy

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying use `std::copy` to copy from two different iterator. But during course of execution these two iterators can be pointing to same location. Why in this situation they do not copy the single characters.

```
std::string str1 = "ABC";
std::string::iterator itr1 = str1.begin();
std::string::iterator itr2 = str1.begin();
std::string result;
std::copy(itr1,itr2,result.begin());
```

Comment: Note that `result` must already have enough room to hold the characters you want to copy in. So you must either create it with the length of 1, or resize it to that length, or use a back inserter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right bound of the range in STL is not inclusive. If you give it the same iterator twice, the result is an empty range. You want this:

```
std::copy(itr1,itr2+1,result.begin());
```

But then, beware that you are writing to a location with no reserved memory, which is Undefined behavior. You must use a `back_insert_iterator`

```
std::copy(itr1,itr2 + 1, std::back_inserter(result));
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `std::string(itr1, itr2 + 1)`

Comment: @ereOn: You mean `std::string result(itr, itr2 + 1)` ?:)

Answer (score 2):

Write :

```
result.resize(1); //it must have some size
std::copy(itr1,itr2 + 1,result.begin());
```

Or better yet.

```
//no need to resize now!
std::copy(itr1,itr2 + N, std::back_inserter(result));
```

where `N` is number of characters you want to copy to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, you could simply do:

```
std::string result(itr1, itr1 + 1);
```

Since `std::string` has [a constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) that takes two iterators to copy its content from.

Now for the explanations:

`std::copy(itr1, itr2, res)` copies all the elements starting at `itr1` and stopping **just before** `itr2` a the location specified by `res`.

That is, if `itr1 == itr2` there is no "gap" between the two iterators and nothing is copied.

That's why the `end()` iterator usually points past the **last element** of a collection.

---

Consider the following vector, `vec`, which has 3 elements:

```
1, 2, 3, X
^        ^
|        | 
|        \-- end() (X indicates a slot past the last element)
\----------- begin()
```

That is, if you use `std::copy()` with `begin()` and `end()` you will actually copy all the elements of `vec`.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `copy()` is the element *after* the last one copied; `str1.end()` would point after the last character, not before it. Your call is asking for 0 character to be copied, and that's what you're getting. You could advance `itr2` by one before making the call.